# Display right image according to screen size

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design

It's maybe an easy question but after some research I didn't find any valid solution.

I use carrierwave to generate multiple versions of an uploaded image. Each image has a specific size for different screen sizes.
For example (in my uploader) I have

```
version :xl
```

for screens larger than 1200px.

How can I use rails to display specific image according to client screen size ?

I know there is gem *responsive-images* but I can't use size.
The subject of responsive images is for the moment quite vast and nobody seems to have the same answer, especially with javascript and html5. How about rails (even if it's server side) ?

Comment: Would some if/else logic in your view or controller help you out? What class does your `version` method belong to? What does `:x1` represent? How many image size options do you have? Do you need to use a particular image or just set the `size` attribute of an `img` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I really wanted to do it in a more *rails way*. I ended up using ajax :

Fire ajax at load page :

```
# assets/javascript/cards/index.js
// fire loading image
$.ajax({
  url: document.URL,
  data: {
    w: window.innerWidth
  }
});
```

In controller, respond to ajax :

```
# controllers/cards_controller.rb
render 'cards/images/loadimage' if request.xhr?
```

Then load your images

```
# cards/images/loadimage.js.erb
<% w = params[:w].to_i %>
document.getElementById('banner-container').innerHTML = "<%= j image_tag @card.banner_type_url(w), class: 'banner' %>";
document.getElementById('logo-container').innerHTML = "<%= j image_tag @card.logo_type(w), class: 'logo' %>";
```

I made in my model a method to return right image given screen width (and based on carrierwave version) :

```
 # models/card.rb
 # returns banner type based on width (w)
 def banner_type_url(w)
   return self.banner.s.url || banner_default('s') if(w <= 768) 
   return self.banner.m.url || banner_default('m') if(w <= 992) 
   return self.banner.l.url || banner_default('l') if(w <= 1200) 
   return self.banner.xl.url || banner_default('xl') if(w <= 1920) 
   return self.banner.full.url || banner_default('full')    
 end
 def banner_default(s)
   "card/banner/#{s}_default-banner.jpg"
 end
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of ways:

1. Load the page with all the paths to various image sizes stored as data attributes, grab the screen width with js, then stick an image tag with the correct path where you want it. Code might look like (not tested, and I've been using coffeescript, so probably missing details):

   ```
   # ruby command line
   $ @image.mobile_asset_url
   => "path/to/mobile/image"
   $ @image.desktop_asset_url
   => "path/to/desktop/image"


   # html.erb
   <img src="" class="placeholder" data-mobile-url=<%=@image.mobile_asset_url%> data-desktop-url=<%=@image.desktop_asset_url%>></div>

   # javascript
   el = $('.placeholder')
   data = el.data();
   width = $(window).width();
   mobile_breakpoint = 480;

   if (width <= mobile_breakpoint) {
     url = data.mobileUrl;
   } else {
     url = data.desktopUrl;
   }

   el.attr('src', url)
   ```
2. Do a server side test not for screen width, but browser type with a gem like [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser), and load smaller images for mobile specific browsers like iOS8. Logic like this might go best in a decorator. I'm  more fluent with Ruby, so an example might look like (this code not tested):

   ```
   # user_decorator.rb, from the Draper gem
   class UserDecorator

     def profile_url
       if mobile_browser?
          "path/to/small/image"
       else
          "path/to/large/image"
       end
     end

     private

     def mobile_browser?
       browser.ios || browser.android || ...
     end

   end
   ```

Comment: I know this is kind of an old answer but I thought I would ask anyway. Will calling the url as a data attribute cause the page to load the asset?

Comment: @DylanLittle no. It's just a string until it's added to an HTML image tag.